# Distinction between different "kinds" of member variables

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, annotations

I'm parsing large XML definition files.
To achieve this I have started making classes for each "type" that you can encounter in the xml file.

```xml
<Element Factor="10">Whatever</Element>
```

Currently I put each `type` from the XML file in it's own class, with a few operators and the members of the type.

However, some of these `types` have both "child elements" and "attributes".

i.e.:

```xml
<MySimpleType min="20" max="100">
    <name>MyName</name>
    <SomeOtherElement>xxxx</SomeOtherElement>
</Mysimpletype>
```

Currently the class would look like this:

```cpp
class MySimpleType{
    std::string MyName;
    TSomeOtherElement SomeOtherElement;
    int min;
    int max;
}
```

I am wondering if there's a way to annotate the class members so that it becomes clear whether the member in question is an attribute or an element.

The elements can have different types (which may be another custom class) and the attributes are mostly built-ins or ADT's.

Is there a way to clearly mark a member as being a 'element' or a 'attribute' ?

(Should it matter, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the built-in compiler, so I'm using c++11)

Comment: The essential difference between child elements and attributes is that attributes are usually of pretty primitive types, i.e. types that can't have children. But I would counsel you not to do this. The trouble with systems that generate code is that they generate code. You don't need anything beyond DOM for processing XML, and if you do you may not need XML in the first place.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks, you're right. However these XML definitions are what the manufacturer of a multitude of products provides for working with said products (think setup over different communication protocols). So while XML isn't the right tool, it's the tool I have :)

Comment: _Is there a way to clearly mark a member as being a 'element' or a 'attribute' ?_ You could wrap even primitive types in wrappers to remark attributes. E.g. `template <typename T> struct AttrT { T value; };`. You could simply doc. this in comments as well. My question is why you need to know from where the data came from?

Comment: Since you have full control over designing this class, yes there is certain "a way to annotate the class members so that it becomes clear whether the member in question is an attribute or an element". You simply implement it, in whichever way works for you. What exactly is your specific C++ question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik my question is specifically about a good way to implement it in C++, as you can see, the problem isn't "designing the class", it is that within a class, members have different meanings besides their type or name. The question thus is, what is the best or a good way to implement such distinction in c++.

Comment: The problem with asking for a "good way to implement it in C++" is that if you ask this question to two C++ developers you will get three different answers. There is no, some kind of, universally established way to do this that will for in every application in existence.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik which is exactly why I'm turning to the collective knowledge of the c++ developers that frequent this site. To get different opinions, techniques and the like. That way I might find a better solution which I (with my limited experience) wouldn't have thought about or thought possible.

Comment: @Scheff sorry, I hadn't seen your final question yet! It's important to be able to tell the difference between elements and attributes because the way you parse them slightly differs. There is also the issue of expandibility/maintainability, an element could get attributes but an attribute can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have some wrapper type to help identify that:

```
template <typename T>
struct attribute { T value; };
```

and so

```
struct MySimpleType
{
    std::string MyName;
    TSomeOtherElement SomeOtherElement;
    attribute<int> min;
    attribute<int> max;
};
```

You might enrich wrapper class so that it behave more like underlying type (`operator T&()`, `operator = (const T&)`, ...)

Comment: Oops. Just saw your answer after I finished my comment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use c++11 attributes to mark your fields:

```
class MySimpleType {
    [[fmashiro::element]] std::string MyName;
    [[fmashiro::element]] TSomeOtherElement SomeOtherElement;
    [[fmashiro::attribute]] int min;
    [[fmashiro::attribute]] int max;
};
```

Although this will generate a warning about unknown attributes.

Another common approach is to use empty macros:

```
#define FM_ELEMENT
#define FM_ATTRIBUTE

class MySimpleType{
    FM_ELEMENT std::string MyName;
    FM_ELEMENT TSomeOtherElement SomeOtherElement;
    FM_ATTRIBUTE int min;
    FM_ATTRIBUTE int max;
};
```

As a final option, just add a `/* attribute */` comment to the declaration.